# unexpected pandas pivot_table on transformation

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I am using pivot_table to transform the following data from row-wise shape to column-wise shape based on the `ITEMID` values:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [36, 36, 36, 36, 36],
               'VALUE': [86, 21, 85, 19, 87],
               'ITEMID': [220045, 220210, 220045, 220210, 220045],
               'TIME': [pd.to_datetime('2134-05-12 13:00:00'),
                             pd.to_datetime('2134-05-12 13:00:00'),
                             pd.to_datetime('2134-05-12 14:00:00'),
                             pd.to_datetime('2134-05-12 14:00:00'),
                             pd.to_datetime('2134-05-12 15:00:00')]})
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(df.head())
    df = df.pivot_table(index=['id', 'TIME'],
                        columns='ITEMID',
                        values='VALUE', aggfunc='sum').reset_index()
    print(df)
```

but I am getting unexpected results:

```
|ITEMID|id |TIME                |220045  |220210  | 
|------|---|--------------------|--------|--------|
|0     |36 |2134-05-12 13:00:00 |86.0    |21.0    |
|1     |36 |2134-05-12 14:00:00 |85.0    |19.0    |
|2     |36 |2134-05-12 15:00:00 |87.0    |NaN     |
```

whereas the columns should be like

```
|id |TIME |220045 |220210 |220045 |220210|220045 |
|---|-----|-------|-------|-------|------|-------|
```

I have an index like column for `ITEMID` and some `ITEMID`s are transformed into the column-wise shape. I am not sure what is causing this result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `ITEMID` is passed as `columns` to `pivot_table`, the resulting dataframe has a non-null name for the columns. Try `rename_axis`:

```
(df.pivot_table(index=['id', 'TIME'],
                        columns='ITEMID',
                        values='VALUE', aggfunc='sum').reset_index()
  .rename_axis(columns=None))
```

Output:

```
   id                TIME  220045  220210
0  36 2134-05-12 13:00:00    86.0    21.0
1  36 2134-05-12 14:00:00    85.0    19.0
2  36 2134-05-12 15:00:00    87.0     NaN
```

Comment: thank you for your response. But, why we do not have separate columns for all `ITEMID`s? I expect the result to have one column for each `ITEMID`.

Comment: duplicated column names are discouraged in Pandas. And the expected output does not specify how you populate the `TIME` column. You should certainly update your question. I am going to delete this answer soon.

Comment: Thank you, this actually makes sense to me. I guess pandas will combine the duplicated columns in the pivot function.